# How to call a bash script from python script with python variable as argument and set pid

Tags: python, bash

I have the following code:

```
port_temp = 8080
process_getpodsnamesipport = subprocess.call(['bash','getpodsnamesipport.sh', port_temp],preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```

I want to do something like:

```
os.killpg(os.getpgid(process_getpodsnamesipport.pid), signal.SIGKILL)
```

to kill the process but it's possible only with subprocess.Popen.

```
os.killpg(os.getpgid(process_getpodsnamesipport.pid), signal.SIGKILL)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'pid'
```

Comment: The process will already have terminated when `call` returns. If you want a parallel process to run while your Python script continues processing, `Popen` is exactly the right thing to use.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, that's what I want. But how do I use ```Popen``` in this case? As in with the argument ```port_temp```

Comment: `Popen` accepts exactly the same sort of first argument as the other `subprocess` functions. I believe you will need `str(port_temp)` for `subprocess.call` too.

Comment: BTW, `bash somescript.sh` is generally considered bad form. Make the *script itself* identify its interpreter in the shebang line, and then you can run `['./somescript', 'arg']` and you aren't suddenly creating bugs if the script's required interpreter changes in the future. (`.sh` filename extensions are bad form -- they imply that `sh` is usable as an interpreter, which is untrue for anything written for `bash`).

Comment: @Rachelia, ...as tripleee said, `p = subprocess.Popen(['./getpodsnamesipport.sh', str(port_temp)])` will create a backgrounded process. (Putting something in the background but still trying to capture output is a different, more complicated matter).

Comment: `call` is *literally* just [a wrapper](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/subprocess.py#L332) around the creation of a `Popen` object that is subsequently waited on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
process_getpodsnamesipport = subprocess.Popen(['./getpodsnamesipport.sh', str(port_temp)],preexec_fn=os.setsid)
    //something something
    os.killpg(os.getpgid(process_getpodsnamesipport.pid), signal.SIGKILL)
```

Comment: Why do that instead of using https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.send_signal ? It's rare to have a genuine need to kill an entire process group, as opposed to writing the subprocess to have signal handlers that do the right thing (or `exec` the code you need to invoke so it isn't delegated to a subprocess at all).

Answer (score -1):

I would use Popen and try something like this:

```
import subprocess
import os
import signal
import pipes

port_temp = 8080
cmd = ["./getpodsnamesipport.sh", str(port_temp)]

# to address Charles Duffy's suggestion for displaying the command
print(' '.join([pipes.quote(s) for s in cmd]))

process_getpodsnamesipport = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                              stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                              shell=False,
                                              preexec_fn=os.setsid)
std_out, std_err = process_getpodsnamesipport.communicate()
```

Comment: The `split()` just creates bugs when you try to pass arguments that have spaces in their data. The underlying operating system interface (on UNIX-family operating systems) is lists of individual strings, one-per-argument; writing your code to reflect that interface means fewer moving parts, and thus less to go wrong.

Comment: BTW, `communicate()` won't return until the subprocess already closed its stdout and stderr, which generally doesn't happen until after it exited, so I don't see what good the `killpg()` is doing.

Comment: The split() is really just for clarity in this case when calling Popen. The code I pulled from needs to display the command that was run as it would be executed on the command line, but I agree this would break if arguments were passed that have spaces.

Comment: Re: clarity, I'd suggest starting with a list and then using `' '.join([pipes.quote(s) for s in arg_list])` to create a string version should there be need for one. That way you get a string that's correct (evaluates to the command in question in any POSIX shell) for any possible argument list, including ones where elements contain literal whitespace. (Substitute `shlex.quote()` for `pipes.quote()` when in Python 3).